# Transpose short columns to row and rearrange the positions using awk/sed

Tags: awk, sed, transpose

I have current dataset like the one below:

```
11 48 5300 8000 1 0
ht2 
ht2 
11 49 5300 8000 1 0
ht2 
ht2 
11 50 5300 8000 2 0
ht2 
ht2 
11 51 5300 8000 2 0
ht2 
ht3 
11 52 5300 8000 2 0
ht2 
ht3
```

I would like to rearrange the data like the following:

```
11 48 5300 8000 1 0 ht2 ht2
11 49 5300 8000 1 0 ht2 ht2
11 50 5300 8000 2 0 ht2 ht2
11 51 5300 8000 2 0 ht2 ht3
11 52 5300 8000 2 0 ht2 ht3
```

I would deeply appreciate any helps/suggestions from you. Thank you in advance.

Comment: it is always better to try something by yourself and post your effort in your question.

Comment: So sorry that I encountered some errors in formatting the data when I tried to edit them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to read three input lines and write them out as one line.  `Awk` has a function, `getline`, that makes this easy:

```
$ awk '{a=$0; getline; b=$0; getline; print a, b, $0}' dataset 
11 48 5300 8000 1 0 ht2 ht2 
11 49 5300 8000 1 0 ht2 ht2 
11 50 5300 8000 2 0 ht2 ht2 
11 51 5300 8000 2 0 ht2 ht3 
11 52 5300 8000 2 0 ht2 ht3
```

Taking each `awk` command in turn:

- a=$0;

  Save the value of the first line in the variable `a`.
- getline;

  Read in the second line.
- b=$0;

  Save the value of the second line in the variable `b`.
- getline;

  Read in the third line.
- print a, b, $0

  Print out all three lines.

Comment: You should avoid using `getline`.  Do a search for it and read the post by `Ed`  http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

Comment: @Jotne  Thanks for that link.  I read it.  If I write code that uses the non-trivial features of `getline`, I shall surely refer to it.

Comment: @Jotne although there are caveats to using getline in cases like this i don't see why people suggest against it ?

Answer (score 1):

`paste -d" " - - - < file` will result in the following output:

```
11 48 5300 8000 1 0 ht2  ht2
11 49 5300 8000 1 0 ht2  ht2 
11 50 5300 8000 2 0 ht2  ht2 
11 51 5300 8000 2 0 ht2  ht3 
11 52 5300 8000 2 0 ht2  ht3
```

Comment: @Jotne Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out. The default delimiter for paste is `tab`

Comment: You still have one space extra. `11 48 5300 8000 1 0 ht2  ht2` Not sure why your output does not show it.

Comment: @Jotne My output actually matches yours. I see that extra space. If I remove the space after each ht2 on every line, I get right output.

Comment: If you look at my output I have to use `f,g $0` and not `f,g,$0` just to prevent the extra space for beeing printed.  This is a small thing, so leave it, and let the OP fix it :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I could not figure out what you meant. Could you give me some more details on paste - - -

Comment: I could get some idea about paste. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk 'NR%3==1 {f=$0} NR%3==2 {g=$0} NR%3==0 {print f,g $0}' file
11 48 5300 8000 1 0 ht2 ht2
11 49 5300 8000 1 0 ht2 ht2
11 50 5300 8000 2 0 ht2 ht2
11 51 5300 8000 2 0 ht2 ht3
11 52 5300 8000 2 0 ht2 ht3
```

Comment: Thank so much for the code. It works for the small subdata set above. However, I could not figure out why it does not work for the below 1 10000 0 0 1 0
ht2 
ht2 
1 8400 0 0 2 0
ht2 
ht2 
1 61 10000 8400 1 0
ht2 
ht2 
1 62 10000 8400 2 0
ht2 
ht2 
1 63 10000 8400 1 0
ht2 
ht2 
1 80 10000 8400 2 0
ht2 
ht2 
1 81 10000 8400 2 0
ht2 
ht2 
1 82 10000 8400 1 0
ht2 
ht2 
1 83 10000 8400 1 0
ht2 
ht2

Comment: @user3874325 Post this data in your original post, since formatting does not work here.

Comment: @user3874325 Is the issue that the output looks like `ht2ht2` instead of `ht2 ht2`?  If so, the issue is that the original data in the question had trailing whitespace after the `ht` lines which `awk` keeps and which made the `print f,g $0` output look correct.  If your new data does not have that whitespace, use `print f,g,$0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "N;N;s/\n/ /g" YourFile
```

load 2 line after current, replace newline by space. Until the structure is like your sample it will work.